# How to execute a web service using php

Tags: php, web-services

I need  to execute a web service from a php page

The web service is located in the following url

https://www.agemni.com/AgemniWebservices/service1.asmx

The Web Service uses a SOAP protocol to exchange messages.

The WSDL info can be located at https://www.agemni.com/AgemniWebservices/service1.asmx?WSDL

The function in that service that we need to use is **ValidateEntity**

*//ValidateEntity("username", "password", "companyID", 2, keys, values)*

So , how can i execute this web service and get result from my php page

Comment: Checkout this post, it's very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805061/php-soap-http-request/8805376

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple example, hope it helps...

```
$service1 = new SoapClient('https://www.agemni.com/AgemniWebservices/service1.asmx');

//here you instanciate your object with those properties
$entity = new Entity();
$entity->strUsername = 'José';
$entity->strPassword = '123';
$entity->strCompanyName = 'Somethin';
$entity->0 //because your type is int

$res = $service1->ValidateEntity($entity);//here you send the information to your service's method, if I'm not mistaken, it must be a object

$res->ValidateEntityResult;//this is the return of your service.
```

As I said, it is really simple but works.

Answer (score 0):

See soap calls help from php.net:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to use PHP's SOAP libraries...

http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php

Answer (score 0):

For https WebServices you need to enable openssl extension. The WS use .net it means that the class use type hinting so you need to create the ValidateEntity class, here's the code:

```
$ws = new soapclient('https://www.agemni.com/AgemniWebservices/service1.asmx?wsdl');
class ValidateEntity {
    public $strUsername,
    $strPassword,
    $strCompanyName,
    $objecttype;
    }

$parameters = new ValidateEntity();
$parameters->strUsername = 'username';
$parameters->strPassword = 'password';
$parameters->strCompanyName = 'company';
$parameters->objecttype = 1;
echo '<pre>';
print_r($ws->ValidateEntity($parameters));
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: check __getTypes() and __getFunctions() for other soap calls

Comment: use $ws->__call('ValidateEntity', array('parameters' => $parameters)); for document/literal style