# Send and return SOAP response using PHP code

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I'm new to this "SOAP" stuff...

Here is the WebService http://www.sdlmi.com/MIHPService/MIHP.Service1.svc?wsdl

I'm using PHP to send and get a response to validate a specific userid. Here is my current PHP code:

```
$userid = $_POST['tendigitid'];
$client = new SoapClient("http://www.sdlmi.com/MIHPService/MIHP.Service1.svc?wsdl");
$result = $client->isPersonEligible(array(....));
```

I'm quite stuck on HOW to send my $userid variable and get the response from it. For the response, I just need a simple message saying that the input is valid or not. Thanks.

Comment: [ideas](http://www.navioo.com/php/tutorials/Using_SOAP_whith_PHP_821.html)

Answer (score 1):

To help you, we'll need further information about the web service you're connecting to. Can you provide a link to the documentation?

As per this [wikipedia article on SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP), ...

> SOAP is a protocol specification for exchanging structured information
>   in the implementation of Web Services in computer networks. It relies
>   on Extensible Markup Language (XML) for its message format

So you'll probably be sending your request information using XML. So, please provide the link to the documentation and you'll get more specific help. You also need to give more information on what you intend to be sending and receiving.

Try looking at these links:

- [PHP SOAP HTTP Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805061/php-soap-http-request)
- [How to post SOAP Request from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471115/how-to-post-soap-request-from-php)
- http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php

Also, I **strongly** suggest you read the StackOverflow FAQ before posting again. Your question is too vague and does not have enough information. I suggest you edit your post accordingly.